# How to get the 'keyword' in domain.com/keyword with Iron Router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I am working on a site where I have to search in the DB for string that come after the / on the root domain. I can't find anything about it in the documentation.
I am trying to make it work with Iron Router but any other suggestion would work out.

Thanks for the help!

Edit: Basically I just want to pass anything that comes after domain.com/ to a variable.

Comment: What's wrong with `route(/:keyword', handler)`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How can I pass the 'keyword' into a global variable so I can use it all over my projects?

Comment: Router.route('/:keyword', function () {
  url_keyword = this.params.keyword;
});

Comment: Don't forget to [edit] to add info. What went wrong with your current code?

Comment: This is the error I get on client side when I am trying to use the url_keyword variable: Uncaught ReferenceError: url_keyword is not defined(anonymous function) Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier.

Comment: Please [edit] new information into the question instead of adding it as a comment.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33221354/edit) your question to add the new information you've disclosed (it will prevent the information from being easily deleted and will increase the chances of potential answerers seeing it).

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33221354/edit) your question with the information posted comments, especially when posting error messages, as the formatting in comments does not allow for code blocks, which makes them a lot harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something i've been doing so maybe it'll lead you down the right path

Route sends URL `params` to `ownedGroupList` template

```
Router.route('/users/:_id/groups', {
    name: 'owned.group.list',
    template: 'ownedGroupList',
    data: function() {
        return {params: this.params};
    }
});
```

Template `ownedGroupList` can access `params` object using `this.data` in `onCreated`, `onRendered`, and `onDestroyed` template event handlers

```
Template.ownedGroupList.onCreated(function(){
    this.subscribe("owned-groups", this.data.params._id );
});
```

Template `ownedGroupList` can access `params` through `this` variable in helper methods

```
Template.ownedGroupList.helpers({
    groups: function() {
        return Groups.find({owner: this.params._id });
    }
});
```

Template `ownedGroupList` can access `params` through `template.data` variable in event handlers

```
Template.ownedGroupList.events({
    'click .a-button': function(event, template) {
        var group = Groups.findOne({owner: template.data.params._id });
        // do something with group
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple route that should do the trick

```
Router.route('/:keyword', {
    name: 'keyword',
    template: 'keywordTemplate',
    data: function() {
        return this.params.keyword;
    }
});
```

This will pass the keyword as the data context to your template and then you can do whatever you want with it. Alternatively you can perform the search straight in the router (especially if you're passing the keyword to a subscription so that the search runs on the server). For example:

```
Router.route('/:keyword', {
    name: 'keyword',
    template: 'keywordTemplate',
    waitOn: function(){
      return Meteor.subscribe('keywordSearch',keyword);
    },
    data: function() {
        return MyCollection.find();
    }
});
```

This second pattern will send your keyword to a subscription named `keywordSearch` that will execute on the server. When that subscription is ready, the route's `data` function will run and the data context passed to your `keywordTemplate` will be whatever documents and fields have been made available in `MyCollection`.